# Retrieve data from Firebase but snaptshop.get returns null

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am really new to Firebase.
I am making an Android app that uses firestore as database. My problem is when I try to check if a certain data exists. It will always say it does not.

This is the method where this is happening.

```
private void usernameInDatabase(final String username){

        if (registration != null)
            registration.remove();

        registration = utilizadores.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                                          @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.w("Utilizadores", "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }
                if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
                    Log.d("Utilizadores", snapshot.getData().toString());
                    Log.d("Utilizadores", username);
                    if (snapshot.get(username) == null) {
                        loginFormState.setValue(new LoginFormState(R.string.utilizadorNaoBaseDados, null));
                        utilizadorNaBaseDados = false;
                        Log.d("Utilizadores", "Not Database :(");
                    } else {
                        utilizadorNaBaseDados = true;
                        Log.d("Utilizadores", "base de dados ;D");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Utilizadores", "Current data: null");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I check the data that I can retrieve from firestore here:

```
                    Log.d("Utilizadores", snapshot.getData().toString());
                    Log.d("Utilizadores", username);
```

This is what I get in logcat:

> {daniel@gmail.com={dataNasc=Timestamp(seconds=862182000, nanoseconds=0), mail=daniel@gmail.com, pass=, nome=Daniel Marco, id=danMar125}, ester@gmail.com={dataNasc=Timestamp(seconds=902876400, nanoseconds=0), mail=ester@gmail.com, pass=, nome=Ester Mendes, id=est124}, ola@g.co=hgjk, marcio@gmail.com={dataNasc=Timestamp(seconds=680914800, nanoseconds=0), mail=marcio@gmail.com, pass=, nome=Márcio Marques, id=marMar123}, marco@gmail.com={dataNasc=Timestamp(seconds=923180400, nanoseconds=0), mail=marco@gmail.com, pass=, nome=Marco António, id=marAnt545}, maria@gmail.com={dataNasc=Timestamp(seconds=877561200, nanoseconds=0), mail=maria@gmail.com, pass=, nome=Maria Antonieta, id=marAnt999}}
>
> daniel@gmail.com

So, I know that the username I am searching is in database, and I know that the data is being retrieved from database, but it keeps acting like it is not.

Can anyone help me, please?

**Edit**

This is my database structure.

[image]

And this is how I defined utilizadores.

```
  DocumentReference utilizadores = db.collection("Domum").document("Utilizador");
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  thanks, I will be more careful next time.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and show us how your `utilizadores` is defined. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated my question. Please let me know if something is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the existens of a user according to the structure of your database, you simply need to use `contains()` method, on the `Map` object that is returned by `document.getData()`. So in code should look like this:

```
utilizadores.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                if (map.containsKey("daniel@gmail.com")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User exists!");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User does not exist!");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you need to get data in realtime, then you should use `addSnapshotListener()`, in the same way as above.

Comment: Thank you very much, @AlexMamo. It is now working. I just don't know why the other way didn't work, because I had already get data from a different firestore database in a similar way. Thank you very much!